# Pagination with Letters as index

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I may have misunderstood what index is, after reading my question, you'll soon realize so please correct me if i was wrong. anyhow,

Is there any tutorial on paginating in codeigniter. Something that is simple and concise, i don't need complex ones since ill have hard time understanding the whole code.

> > **A** B C D
>
> - Ants
> - Airplane

Something like above, instead of number paging, would it be possible to paginate by first letters?

Ive encountered alot of sites that have these although im not sure if coding this would need any add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to build one. already this topic is disccused in CI forum.
Please check the forum link:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/164849/

Comment: I thought to myself, I think its very simple but complex to code.

Ill probably need to use AJAX and load different pages for A-Z
then inside those, ill paginate. right?

Comment: Yes. You can do it in normal page load or Ajax. However concept is same.

Comment: a normal page wouldnt impress my instructor. AJAX would be best. but i was really trying to avoid AJAX or anything that involves that or jquery. The syntax are hard to understand. 

I can deal with javascript since its more understandable. But to me, im inexperienced i see ajax and jquery as bunch of $##@$&& with few asdqwejxv in them. :(

Comment: cool. It's all simple and easy to learn. You will get all help in Stackoverflow and google.