# Creating A-Z links in CI and pagination results manipulation

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I wanted to create a link of A-Z. This is for my pagination.

For example, i have paginated results from a table, So i have to make links above the results from A-Z. If i click A. only those results which have A as their `$position[0];` should be shown.

This is just a sample php code i just made. Its not on Codeigniter so the links are made by html code. The way i will implement in later in my CI is that i will use anchor tags and uri segment for each link to send out the corresponding letter the link that has been picked.

Anyhow, sample code.

```
<?php

$string = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
$letter_array =  explode(' ',$string);
foreach($letter_array as $key=>$letter)
{
?>
<a href=""><?php echo $letter; ?></a>
<?php
}
$sample_results = "Airplane,Car,Truck";

$array_results = explode(',',$sample_results);

foreach($array_results as $key=>$val)
{
if($val[0] == "A")
{
echo $val;
}
}
?>
```

It works, and prints a result.

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z Airplane

Is there any faster way of declaring an array of A-Z letter in codeigniter? like somehow, assuming this is right. `$array = array("A-Z","a-z");`So when i loop this it would print letters A to Z / a to z.

and lastly, is there any way of manipulating query results by filtering results with only those that first letter is what the user picked. Like in the where clause in CI. can i add a code like `where("name".[0],$letter_link)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination with Letters as index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525182/pagination-with-letters-as-index)

Comment: The foreach(range('a', 'z') as $letter)  answers my other question. Anyway, Just a question, on paginating using letters. Ill use the links for chars instead of numbers right? what if i have 100 results for A. Do i need to paginate again that 100 to maybe 10 per page?

Comment: I didn't see your comment before, Anyway for your new question yes you have to use another pagination. Please check my web site http://www.vanmaram.com/browse/english/a/1 in this you have letter 'a' and '1'. Here 'a' is for letter pagination and '1' for pagination inside letter 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/164849/)

1. declaring an array of A-Z letter in codeigniter. There is a function in php called

   range()
   So your code can be like this

   foreach(range('a', 'z')as $key=>$letter)

see the [manual](https://www.php.net/range), Which gives you a array within the range you provided.

2. This code will help you.

   ```
    <?php
   ```

   class Books_model extends Model {
   function Books_model() {
   parent::Model();
   }

   ```
    function get_list($char = FALSE) {
      $this->db->from('books');
      if($char !== FALSE) {
        $this->db->like('title', $char, 'after'); // here is the answer
      }
      $this->db->order_by('title', 'asc');
      $result = $this->db->get();
      if($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $result->result_array();
      } else {
        return array();
      }
    }
   ```

   }